# Service routing WCF RestFul/JSON

Tags: wcf, rest, routes

What would be the best approach to use the build-in ServiceRouter in 4.0 for WCF/JSON services?

Does anybody know any good article sample about this? I  need to know how to filter the messages for an specific service in order to assing them like with the case WCF/SOAP

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for answer myself and this is what I've found:
[The Routing Service does not currently support routing of WCF REST services. To route REST calls, consider using System.Web.Routing or Application Request Routing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee517423.aspx)